# I can't associate 2 objects in the Rails console manually without getting a NoMethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have 2 models:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pics
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Pic.rb

```
class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

They are associated with each by a one-to-many association, however, I can't seem to associate 2 objects in the rails console without receiving a NoMethod error:

```
2.3.0 :001 > @user = User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id"   
ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "nono@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-12-20
10:52:10", updated_at: "2016-12-20 10:52:10"> 
2.3.0 :002 > @pic = Pic.first
  Pic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "pics".* FROM "pics"  ORDER BY "pics"."id" ASC
LIMIT 1
 => #<Pic id: 1, title: "Yo! My first post!", description: "Wazzaaappp this
is Wali", created_at: "2016-12-20 10:30:45", updated_at: "2016-12-20 
10:30:45", user_id: nil> 
2.3.0 :003 > @pic.user = @user

NoMethodError: undefined method `user=' for #<Pic:0x00000002918758>
Did you mean?  user_id=
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-
4.2.5/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
       from (irb):3
```

EDIT: This is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161220102651) do

  create_table "pics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "pics", ["user_id"], name: "index_pics_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name:  
  "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: did you `reload!` your console and `find` Pic after you update your `Pic.rb`

Comment: Yes, it didn't seem load reloading the console worked.

Comment: did you reload the model too? Because if you dont it will be the old object

Comment: Nope, how can I? Sorry,I'm new to Rails. I tried calling User.reload in the console but I received a nomethod error.

Comment: just `@pic = Pic.first` will do

Comment: Ah, no that doesn't seem to work either. :( Resetting the model and following the previous sequence still beings the same error.

Comment: please restart your console, because your code seems to be in order and should not cast that error

Comment: Ah! It worked! I exited out of the C9 IDE and rebooted it, and that seemed to do the trick. Thank you, please answer this question so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart/reload the console to have the changes have an effect